# Flutter web app is not supporting in IE11. Shows empty page

Tags: flutter-web

Flutter web app(Sample app) is not supporting in IE11. Shows empty page and remaining browsers(Chrome, Firefox, edge) its working fine. Any solution for this IE11 issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Sample app so we can try it. When I look at flutter there seem to be a lot of sample apps so I don't know which one to try. Also, what errors do you see on the browser's console?

Comment: I am using Simple Add count, basic app. I am getting 'Syntax error' in 'main_module.bootstrap.js'. Thanks for the reply @AHaworth.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't find the example, please provide a link. Also please let us know what errors you are seeing in your browser's dev tools console - it sounds as though the error is because some JS that is not available in IE is being used but we can't know until we look at the code and/or the errors.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web   - sample flutter web app link that I am using.  Error that I am getting in IE11 is 'SCRIPT1002:Syntax error main_module.bootstrap.js(496,44)'. @AHaworth.

Comment: This issue is probably better dealt with on a flutter (github) site rather than here but I have put up an answer here as far as it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at various discussions about flutter it was reported as not working with IE or Edge earlier in 2020 but it now works with Edge (probably because Edge has moved towards Chrome). I did not find any comment that says it now works on IE and trying other examples they work on Chrome and Edge as of today but not on IE11.

Also, the test example given does not work on Firefox either.

There is some hint in the discussions on `[https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web][1]` that they were tracking down the problems in Edge (before Edge moved) but I could not find any hint that they would be working on IE.

It may be best to repeat the question to the flutter community - but it would not be surprising if they were not going to work on an IE version as it is slowly dying out.

Having said all that, the error now posted by the questioner points at an incompatibility with the version of Bootstrap being used. Several places in searching for this come up with the recommentdation that this should be added in the head of the code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

It may be worth raising this with flutter themselves - maybe they are using the wrong version of Bootstrap or need to do something like the above? (to prevent old version of IE run).
[1]: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web